# AngularJS, use scope in directive in an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, resources, scope, directive

I want to use $resource in a directive, bind the result to the scope and then use it in a template within the directive itself. Like this:

```
.directive('myCategory', ['$compile', 'webService', function($compile, webService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            scope.categories =  webService.query({resourceName:'category'});
        },
        template: '<li ng-repeat="category in categories><a href="#/blog/category/{{category.id}}">{{category.name}}</a></li>'

    };
}]);;
```

Comment: ah, never mind, it was just a typo

    template: '<li ng-repeat="category in categories"><a href="#/blog/category/{{category.id}}">{{category.name}}</a></li>'

I forgot the double quotes (") after categories in my ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

you should probably have your data accessed in the controller, not directive.  try this

```
.directive('myCategory', function() {
          return {
              restrict: 'E',
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {

      },
      template: '<li ng-repeat="category in categories><a href="#/blog/category/{{category.id}}">{{category.name}}</a></li>'

          };
}]);;
```

then the controller...

```
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, webService) {

$scope.categories =  webService.query({resourceName:'category'});

}
```

should work, make sure your controller encapsulates your directive.